# Move value to from one column to another and replace with NA

Tags: r

I have a column in my data frame called `size` that has a mix of numbers and characters. I'd like to move all the character values to the next column over and replace them with NA's. Here's what my data looks like now.

```
size <- c(680,1800,720,"apartment","loft") 
type <- c("apartment","available now","apartment","available now","available jul 20")
data <- cbind(size,type)


     size        type              
[1,] "680"       "apartment"       
[2,] "1800"      "available now"           
[3,] "720"       "apartment"       
[4,] "apartment" "available now"   
[5,] "loft"      "available jul 20"
```

And this is what I'd like it to look like:

```
     size        type              
[1,] "680"       "apartment"       
[2,] "1800"      "available now"           
[3,] "720"       "apartment"       
[4,] NA          "apartment"
[5,] NA          "loft"
```

Unfortunately, there is no uniform value in the `type` column to call on to help replace the values of `size`. I was hoping to avoid creating a vector of unique types to call on because those unique values may change. What I wish for is a way to delineate character vs numeric within a diverse column. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
rep.rows <- !grepl("^[0-9]+$", data[ ,"size"])
data[rep.rows, ] <- cbind(NA, data[rep.rows, "size"])
```

Produces:

```
     size   type           
[1,] "680"  "apartment"    
[2,] "1800" "available now"
[3,] "720"  "apartment"    
[4,] NA     "apartment"    
[5,] NA     "loft"
```

Here we first find which rows have something other than numbers for column 1, and then replace those with the modified data.

Comment: This is really close! Thanks! Two questions: when I apply this to my whole dataset, I get this error `> data[rep.rows, ] <- cbind(NA, data[rep.rows, "size"])`
`Error in [<-.data.frame(*tmp*, rep.rows, , value = c(NA, NA, NA, NA,  : 
  replacement has 3508 items, need 22802`. Another question, just out of curiosity, what part of the code is replacing the parts of the `type` column? That's pretty wild.

Comment: I think part of the problem may be that your code works for a matrix and the dataset is actually a dataframe. When I isolate the two columns `size` and `type` as a matrix, it works. I can then just replace those columns into the dataframe.

Comment: Does your data set have more than two columns and you're trying to shift them all by one?  If so the second line should be: `cbind(NA, data[rep.rows, -1])` assuming `size` is the first column.  If it isn't the solution is a little bit more complicated.

Comment: It is more than two columns, `size` and `data` are located in the 7th and 8th column.

Comment: If you don't need to shift all the columns, then `data[rep.rows, c(7, 8)] <- cbind(NA, data[rep.rows, "size"])` should work.  Just make sure that you create your `data.frame` with `stringsAsFactors=F` as otherwise it might complain when you try to add values to the `type` column.

Comment: Thanks! It worked! After re-importing the data with `stringsAsFactors=F`, I had to `data$size <- as.character(data$size)` and 
`data$type <- as.character(data$type)`